# Back propagation cost function formula - what does $\sigma$ mean?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I'm a beginner in ML, and have a question on back propagation cost function.

I'm reading the material on this [link](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html). In the below screen, since $a$ is the neuron's output, then why $a = \sigma(z)$ instead of $a = z$ directly?

What does $\sigma$ mean exactly here?

[image]

Comment: Sigma is called an activation function. Its used to add nonlinearity to the network.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks a lot Matthew! Yea, I missed the part for activation function.